# How to add missing keys with null/blank values in nested JSON which have nested list of dict using python/pyspark

Tags: python, json, list, pyspark

I have a JSON as below :

```
{"id": 1, "type": "int", "data": {"key0": "val1", "key2": "val2"}}
{"id": 2, "type": "int", "data": {"key2": "val3", "key3": "val4"}}
{"id": 3, "type": "int", "data": {"key1": "val5", "key3": "val6"}}
```

Now when flattening using pyspark I need to have all the columns as key0,key1,key2,key3
but when selecting columns data.key3 or any other key which is not present in either record the
job fails with the error "pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'No such struct field"
Tried passing schema but the issue still persisted and tried with the withColumn approach using when but that is also failing.
Have someone faced similar type of issue and fixed kindly help.

Below is the way I am reading schema:

```py
df_landing = spark.read.format("json").option("multiline", "true").load(input_file)
print(df_landing.printSchema())
```

below is the result :

```
root 
|-- data: struct (nullable = true) 
| |-- key0: string (nullable = true) 
| |-- key2: string (nullable = true) 
|-- id: long (nullable = true) 
|-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `df.printSchema()`?

Comment: root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Could you edit your post to add it in the question?   The schema doesn't seem right. `data` only has `key0` and `key2`. It seems you are reading only first line of JSON. Maybe there is an issue on how you are reading the data.

could you also post the code how you are reading the JSON into the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `.option("multiline", "true")`, this is when 1 JSON record is go across multiple lines.

Your data is JSONL, each line is valid JSON and each JSON doesn't go across multiple lines.

If you remove the option, you should see the schema like this.

```py
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

Then, you can use this code to expand the struct.

```py
df_landing = df_landing.select('id', 'type', 'data.*')
```

```
# df_landing.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|type|key0|key1|key2|key3|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1| int|val1|null|val2|null|
|  2| int|null|null|val3|val4|
|  3| int|null|val5|null|val6|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
```